# How to display most popular posts from certain category in sidebar?

Tags: posts, widgets, sidebar

Assume I have a menu based on categories (jazz, rock, classic). I would like to display most popular posts (in sidebar widget) depending on which page I am (on jazz page I would like to have most popular jazz posts and so on). I tried:

```
// Get current page category
$categories_popular = get_the_category();
$page_category_name_popular = $categories_popular[0]->cat_name;

while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post(); 
get_the_category_list();
if ( in_category($page_category_name_popular) ) { // Check if post matches page category ?>
...
```

But this code results in some strange errors (sometimes it works, sometimes not). What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

EDIT
The whole function (for highest numer of comments, but issue is the same):

```
function wpb_most_commented_posts() { 

// start output buffering
    ob_start(); ?>

    <div class="most-commented">

        <?php 
        $categories_commented = get_the_category();
        $page_category_name_commented = $categories_commented[0]->cat_name; // Get page category. Should be cat_slug??  

        // Run WP_Query
        $query = new WP_Query(array('orderby' => 'comment_count', 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'category_name' => $page_category_name_commented));

        //loop
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <article class="cp-wrap cp-small clearfix">
                    ...
                </article>     
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php

$output = ob_get_clean(); 

return $output; 
}
```

Comment: do you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and are you receiving any error messages? your query code for `$popularpost` is also missing here, not sure why you're not querying for the category directly rather than testing if it's in a category inside the loop.

Comment: Like this? `$categories_commented = get_the_category();
$page_category_name_commented = $categories_commented[0]->cat_name;

$query = new WP_Query(array('orderby' => 'comment_count', 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'category_name' => $page_category_name_commented));`

Comment: `category_name` expects a slug, not the name, which may differ. it's also redundant to check `in_category` within the loop, since your query explicitly requests posts in that category.

Comment: I removed the if statement before I started to match category in query, but now the result is only one, last category on every page. I will put the whole code under EDIT in my question.

Comment: Quess I figured it out: `$categories_commented = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$page_category_name_commented = $categories_commented->cat_ID;
  
  $query = new WP_Query(array('orderby' => 'comment_count', 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'cat' => $page_category_name_commented));`